# Seasonality is always 7 when running seasonal_decompose(). Why is that?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, statsmodels

I have been running seasonal_decompose() from the statsmodels on about 20 totally different datasets. Is it standard that the seasonality is 7 when looking at a dataset with day frequency?

Here is a picture as an example of one dataset decomp. I zoomed in on the seasonality so that you can see that it is again 7 days:

[image]

Why is it always 7 days though? I wouldn't expect it to be always 7 days and the datasets are all different from each other, so by now I think that either this is total coincidence or this is because of seasonal_decompose().

But looking at how seasonal_decompose() in the statsmodels documentation , it uses LOESS to figure out the seasonality. If I look at the formula, it should be able to find different frequencies of the seasonality. I just need to verify that I am not wrong here: Is it pure coincidence that all of my datasets produce a 7 day frequency of the seasonality?

Comment: It depends on what you're tracking.  Anything that is impacted by weekends (energy use, pollution, fuel consumption, traffic, mass transit) is obviously going to be very strongly aligned to a weekly cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `seasonal_decompose` has nothing to do with LOESS, for decomposition based on LOESS you need to use `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL`. `seasonal_decompose` does not infer periodicity based on data in any way. You only have two options:

1. State periodicity explicitly using `period` argument
2. Do not state periodicity, leaving `period` argument at `None`. In this case you have to feed `pandas` dataframe with datetime index to `seasonal_decompose`, and periodicity will be inferred from datetime index frequency label, otherwise it will throw an error. It first fetches frequency label: `pfreq = getattr(getattr(x, "index", None), "inferred_freq", None)` (in your case frequency label will be `'D'`, meaning daily), then it converts it to periodicity using `statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.freq_to_period` (in your case frequency label `'D'` will be converted to `7`, and that will be used as periodicity, hence the results you get)